# Preparation for Data Binding: How should I design my data model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to structure my data, so I can bind it from an SQL database (maybe with Entity Framework).

This is the shape of my data model:

```
- ListView (Books)
  - ListView (Chapters)
    - ListView (Content)
      - ListView (Interpretations)
        - TextBox (Idea)
        - TextBox (Reference)
```

The indented items should depend on their parents.

I created a class for each content type (Book, Chapter, Content, Interpretation) and tried to link them with each other:

```
class Book {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public List<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

class Chapter {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}

class Content {
    public List<Interpretation> Interpretations { get; set; }
}

class Interpretation {
    public string Idea { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

Is this approach fine? Or do I have to change it a bit, so that data binding in wpf can work?

Comment: First thing: A ListView has nothing to do with a data model. It's natural to think that way, but you should try to break the habit. You have collections of things. Most of those things have child collections of other things. One type of thing has two editable text properties. Maybe the views you eventually write will display the collections in ListViews, maybe you'll change your mind about that. Your POCO classes need to be public and they need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` -- but Entity Framework will do that for you if you go that route.

Comment: ...another option would be to write viewmodel classes which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and mirror the POCO classes. That's preferable in a more serious application. Either way, the objects your views bind to need to implement `INPC`, and (forgot this bit) their collections should be `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`, so that additions and removals will raise notifications to the UI that the collection has changed.

Comment: oh, that is interesting, thank you! I am curious about your complete answer !

Comment: I just mention that nesting ListView can be a bad idea. It will be much better to use ListView on top level and rest let data template to take care combination of ItemsControl for nested collections.